# How to deserialize a custom readonly struct requiring ctor invocation using protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, struct, protobuf-net

I have created a custom (readonly) struct to encapsulate a decimal. I am using the struct everywhere, including a public-facing API consumed by various programming languages, and therefore would like to avoid exposing decimal data types.

This shows the relevant parts of the struct:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = false, ImplicitFields=ImplicitFields.None)]
public readonly struct Amount
{
    [ProtoIgnore]
    public const decimal Scale = 100000m;

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public decimal Value { get; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public long ScaledValue { get; }

    public Amount(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
        ScaledValue = checked((long)(value * Scale).Round(0));
    }

    public Amount(long scaledValue)
    {
        Value = scaledValue / Scale;
        ScaledValue = scaledValue;
    }        

    public static Amount CreateFrom(long scaledValue) => new Amount(scaledValue);
}
```

The problem I have is that the ctor is not invoked during deserialization, despite the SkipConstructor=false on ProtoContract, causing only the ScaledValue property to be correctly initialized.

I cannot use a ProtoAfterDeserialization method to set the Value property because the struct is readonly.

I have tried to configure a custom factory method for protobuf-net to use when creating the object, by doing this:

```
var createFrom = typeof(Amount).GetMethod("CreateFrom", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(long) }, null);
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Amount)].SetFactory(createFrom);
```

But this invariably results in "*InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.*". I have verified that the CreateFrom method is found (so am passing in a valid MethodInfo object).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct`, and `readonly struct` in particular, is something that I plan to address more in v3 which has plans for new serializer APIs. In the interim, it isn't a scenario it handles well, but your best bet may be "surrogates" - meaning the serializer largely ignores `Amount`, using *something else* more serialization-friendly in its place. This also means you can remove any serializer attributes or APIs from `Amount`:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // only need to do this once, *before*
        // serializing/deserialing anything
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Amount), false)
            .SetSurrogate(typeof(AmountSurrogate));

        // test it works
        var obj = new Foo { Amount = new Amount(123.45M) };
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
        System.Console.WriteLine(clone.Amount.Value);
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Amount Amount { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
struct AmountSurrogate
{ // a nice simple type for serialization
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public long Value { get; set; }

    // operators define how to get between the two types
    public static implicit operator Amount(AmountSurrogate value)
        => Amount.CreateFrom(value.Value);
    public static implicit operator AmountSurrogate(Amount value)
        => new AmountSurrogate { Value = value.ScaledValue };
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much! (now all I need is to eliminate that pesky wrapper, so for the public-facing API I will probably resort to using a shadow property).